# Karm Webpack Warning for "mocked" image URL

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, webpack-dev-server, karma-webpack

I am testing an Angular app and, for specs, I'm supplying a non-existent URL for an image (e.g. `/foo1.jpg`).

The tests run okay, however, webpack throws a warning:

```sh
15 04 2022 06:28:22.123:WARN [web-server]: 404: /_karma_webpack_/foo1.jpg
```

Is there a way I can either suppress the warning (I get a LOT of them), or better mock an image path?

Comment: Add an image to your assets folder and give its URL to your mocks ?

Comment: The images are dynamically provided from a webservice. Wouldn't it be bad form to create some random `foo1.jpg` image in my assets folder just for testing? After all, the image isn't being deployed.

Comment: You can opt it out of the production build with a given config in `angular.json` if need be, but juste the favicon should do the trick I guess ?

Comment: Also, you have [this kind of utilitaries online](https://picsum.photos/)

Comment: good thought on the favicon.ico. I used that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that, happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

As @temp_user suggested, I simply changed my references to `/favicon.ico`.